# Is there use case for implementing a callback if a future is returned?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, asynchronous-programming

If I have function which returns a future, is there any reason to also include a callback where the callback is simply called right before the future completes?

The only advantage I can think of would be to guarantee that some action be performed prior to any tasks pending on the future and also that the action be guaranteed to occur within the same thread of the future's callee.

Are there any use cases or practical applications for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Guava Library has the concept of a [ListenableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListenableFuture.html) and a [SettableFuture](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SettableFuture.html).

A `ListenableFuture` [allows you to register callbacks](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained) to be executed once the computation is complete, or if the computation is already complete, immediately. This simple addition makes it possible to efficiently support many operations that the basic `Future` interface cannot support.

Because the `Runnable` interface does not provide direct access to the `Future` result, users who want such access may prefer [`Futures.addCallback`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#addCallback(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture,%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureCallback)).  A `FutureCallback<V>` implements two methods:

- `onSuccess(V)`, the action to perform if the future succeeds, based on its result
- `onFailure(Throwable)`, the action to perform if the future fails, based on the failure

The most important reason to use `ListenableFuture` is that it becomes possible to have complex chains of asynchronous operations.

When several operations should begin as soon as another operation starts ("fan-out"), `ListenableFuture` just works: it triggers all of the requested callbacks. With slightly more work, we can "fan-in," or trigger a ListenableFuture to get computed as soon as several other futures have all finished: see [the implementation of Futures.allAsList](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#line.1276) for an example.

In .NET, these concepts are implemented using `Task`, `TaskCompletionSource` and `ContinueWith`.

Comment: In Java 1.8 it is called CompletionStage.

Comment: Google APIs for Android has a similar TaskCompletionSource class, which allows creation of `Task`-enabled APIs. ("Tasks" are asynchronous operations with callbacks.)